# Ubuntu 19.04 screen autorotate not working Lenovo Yoga X390

Tags: gnome, lenovo

I've just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on Lenovo Yoga X390 convertible laptop. Autorotation does not work in Gnome Desktop but surprisingly works well during GDM when login prompt is displayed. 
iio-sensor-proxy service seems to be OK,

```
systemctl status iio-sensor-proxy.service
iio-sensor-proxy.service - IIO Sensor Proxy service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iio-sensor-proxy.service; static;  
vendor 
Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-08-25 09:16:17 CEST; 12min ago
Main PID: 1437 (iio-sensor-prox)
Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
Memory: 2.0M
CGroup: /system.slice/iio-sensor-proxy.service
       └─1437 /usr/sbin/iio-sensor-proxy

sie 25 09:16:17 N317-PC10 systemd[1]: Starting IIO Sensor Proxy service...
sie 25 09:16:17 N317-PC10 systemd[1]: Started IIO Sensor Proxy service.
```

monitor-sensor can recognize screen rotation well:

```
monitor-sensor 
Waiting for iio-sensor-proxy to appear
+++ iio-sensor-proxy appeared
=== Has accelerometer (orientation: normal)
=== No ambient light sensor
Accelerometer orientation changed: right-up
Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
Accelerometer orientation changed: left-up
Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
```

But Gnome desktop won't rotate. I believe it is to be done automatically but it does not work. Any hints? Surely I can write a script that runs in the background, monitor monitor-sensor and reacts appropriately to the reported rotation but on my previous Yoga S1 it was working out of the box without any additional setup.

Update 4.12.2019:
Seems there is no update to the service sent from the accelerometer.
I can manually trigger it via i.e.

```
cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_accel_x_raw
```

still it worked and stopped since latest updates, eventually randomly fails.

Comment: I have the same problem and looked into it briefly a couple of months ago; iio-sensor-proxy working fine and monitor-sensor changing when the screen was rotated, but gnome desktop not rotating. It seemed to be a gnome configuration or dbus problem. In desperation I deleted all the gnome configuration files I could find in my home directory (e.g., ~/.gnome/, ~/.config/gnome*) and

Comment: ... and that seemed to fix it.  But I subsequently upgraded to 19.10 and it broke again (sensor-monitor still working). This time I haven't bothered with it but if you're desperate give it a try.